# In Angularjs, how to ensure template compilation with dynamic model names only after completing all the promises in the for loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-compile, angularjs-templates

I am using Angularjs and c3 charts directives. My template compilation code   is

```
  angular.element(document.body).append($compile(template)($scope));
```

I want this template compilation code to be executed only after all the promises inside the for loop are completed. Can any one help me how can I achieve it? And also for dynamically assigning model names I have used $scope[data.chartIdent], is it right way? The following is the sample code of my controller.

```
                  var chartTabs =   [
                                   {
                                      title:' Spend',
                                      pages:[
                                         {
                                            chart_Id:0,
                                            chart_name:"C0",
                                            chart_type:"line",
                                            chart_call_name:"spendAmount"
                                         },
                                         {
                                             chart_Id:1,
                                            chart_name:"C1",
                                            chart_type:"bar"
                                            chart_call_name:"spendItems"
                                         }
                                      ]
                                   }
                                ];

            var chartArray = chartTabs .pages;

var template = '<div class= "chartsDiv">';

            for(var i = 0; i < chartArray .length; i++) {
                      var  eachChart= chartArray [i];
             var chartIdent = "chart" + i ;

              var chartPromise = dataService.getDataForC3Chart(chart_call_name);

                    chartPromise .then(function (data) {
                        $scope[data.chartIdent] = {

                                            data : {
                                                x: 'x',
                                            columns :data.columns,
                                           type : data.chart_type 
                                            },
                                            axis : {
                                                x: {
                                                    type: 'timeseries',  
                                                    tick:  format: function(value) {                                                         
                                                     var month = value.getUTCMonth() + 1;
                                                     var year = value.getUTCFullYear();
                                                     return  month + '-' + year;
                                                   }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            subchart : {
                                                show : true
                                            }

                                        };
                                }    


                        }, function (error) {
                        $scope[data.chartIdent] = {};
                            alert(error);
                        });

template += ' <div class="col"> <p class="graphtitle">' + eachDashboard.chart_name + ' </p> <c3-simple id = "chart' + i + '" config="chart' + i + '" ></c3-simple> </div>';

                }

    template += ' </div>';

angular.element(document.body).append($compile(template)($scope));
```

using $q.all, how to formulate the template dynamically, here 'i' values are not avaialable for  the template as we are out of for loop.

```
$scope.createDashboradsforeachTab = function(eachTab) {




            var dashboardslayoutArray = eachTab.pages;
                    var promises = [];  
                    var template = '<div class= "chartsDiv">';

                for(var i = 0; i < dashboardslayoutArray.length; i++) {
                    var  eachChart= chartArray [i];
             var chartIdent = "chart" + i ;

              var chartPromise = dataService.getDataForC3Chart(chart_call_name);

      var chartPromise = dataService.getDataForC3Chart(chart_call_name);
       promises.push(chartPromise);


                }

                $q.all(promises)
  .then(function(data){
    // all promises were resolved here

                    $scope[data.chartIdent] = {
                                            data : {
                                                x: 'x',
                                            columns :data.columns,
                                           type : data.chart_type 
                                            }
                                        };
  },function(error) {
                                $scope[data.chartIdent] ={};
                                    alert(error);
                                }
                                );


    template += ' <div class="col"> <p class="graphtitle">' + eachDashboard.chart_name + ' </p> <c3-simple id = "chart' + i + '" config="chart' + i + '" ></c3-simple> </div>';



   template += ' </div>';

angular.element(document.body).append($compile(template)($scope));

                            }
```

Comment: You can combine promisses into one promise.all() Look at docs here https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to collect all the promises into an array and use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all):

```
var promises = [];

for(var i = 0; i < chartArray.length; i++) {
  var chartPromise = dataService.getDataForC3Chart(chart_call_name);
  promises.push(chartPromise);
}

$q.all(promises)
  .then(function(data){
    // all promises were resolved here
  });
```

**Off Topic**: please [read more about Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) so that you won't do things like: `angular.element(document.body).append($compile(template)($scope));`

Comment: ok thanks, but using $q.all, how can I get those template model values dynamically (which needs i value from the for loop). As I am relatively new to Angular js, right know I don't have idea how replace correctly, angular.element(document.body).append($compile(template)($scope)); I need some time to study all these.  I am going through the link you have provided, thanks. I have edited the question with the additional information using $q.all. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean, and it seems like it's a different question. I suggest you try and formulate it with a small example and a new question on SO.